# NodeJS: Write a js object to file and do exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, serialization

To clarify, I have a JS object like so

```
let foo = { 
  fieldA: 'local',
  fieldB:
   [ 'val1',
     'val2',
     'val3' ],
  fieldC: [],
  fieldD: 10,
  fieldE:
   [ { propA: 1,
       propB: 'foo' } ]
}
```

I'd like to write it to a `foo.js` file and have it exported like `exports.foo = {}`

eg:

```
exports.foo = { 
   fieldA: 'local',
   fieldB:
    [ 'val1',
      'val2',
      'val3' ],
   fieldC: [],
   fieldD: 10,
   fieldE:
    [ { propA: 1,
       propB: 'foo' } ]
}
```

I got the write part by doing `fs.writeFileSync('./foo.js', JSON.stringify(foo, null, 2));` and it comes out as, ofcourse a stringified version:

```
{ 
  "fieldA": "local",
  "fieldB":
   [ "val1",
     "val2",
     "val3" ],
  "fieldC": [],
  "fieldD": 10,
  "fieldE":
   [ { "propA": 1,
       "propB": "foo" } ]
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What's wrong with this? Using JSON.stringify() transforms the object to JSON, and if you read the file you can transform it to an object using JSON.parse(). If you want to output JS object properties you can use util.inspect()

Comment: `fs.writeFileSync` just writes the argument to a file. The argument is the result of `JSON.stringify()` which is the stringified representation of the object. If you want js code in the resulting file you will have to construct it yourself (or maybe there is already a module for that in npm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to output the object's properties like you have defined you can use `util.inspect()`. Note, you have to output the rest of the JS statement yourself. For example:

https://repl.it/@mwittig/Object

```
const util = require('util')

let foo = { 
  fieldA: 'local',
  fieldB:
   [ 'val1',
     'val2',
     'val3' ],
  fieldC: [],
  fieldD: 10,
  fieldE:
   [ { propA: 1,
       propB: 'foo' } ]
}

console.log("let foo = " + util.inspect(foo, {showHidden: false, compact: false, depth: null}))
```

Comment: awesome! Thank you so much